# unexpected bracket when using curl_exec()

Tags: bash, curl

I can't seem to figure out this trivial error. My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl \
  -F _ggi_project=PPHWeb2 \
  -F _ggi_origin=query \
  -F _ggi_target_pipeline=1 \
  -F MODELNAME=HumDiv \
  -F UCSCDB=hg19 \
  -F SNPFUNC= \
  -F NOTIFYME=myemail@gmail.com \
  -F _ggi_batch_file=@$1 \
  -D - http://genetics.bwh.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/ggi/ggi2.cgi;

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
echo "My results"; echo $results
```

which sends my request off fine, but I wanted to store the ouput of curl to a bash variable. I however get:

`/usr/local/bin/polyphen.sh: 15: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

what is going on?

Comment: `$result = curl_exec( $ch );` looks like `php` code to me, I doubt it is necessary here. The first part of your code should execute the command fine. If you combine it with the below answer you should get the output into the `results` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use brackets when calling bash commands or functions, simply put the name and arguments separated by spaces:

```
curl_exec $ch
```

If you want to store the result in a variable, you can do it with:

```
result=$(curl_exec $ch)
```

It executes the `curl_exec` command on a subshell, and returns the output of the execution as a string that you later assign to the `result` variable.

Note that the variable being assigned must not have the `$` sign prepended, and that the `=` sign must be next to the variable, without spaces between the variable and it.